# Intellij Command Line Tools wildcards

Tags: java, shell, intellij-idea, command-line-tool

I'm using Intellij2016 and I would like to add and external tool (a linux rm invocation) in order to delete the content of a specific directory every time I debug my java application. I tried using the command line tools Console but when using * wildcard Intellij seems to ignore wildcards (the same behaviour with ls and so on). Is there a way to use wildcards in Intellij command line tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162745#tab=Comments) about wildcards and External Tools (command line parameters).